# remove comma within values in comma-delimited table column

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I'm trying to remove all the commas in a column, for example:

column 1 contains:

```
1,232, 3,123, 123, 32,223
```

How do I remove the commas so that it updates the rows to:

```
1232, 3123, 123, 32223
```

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(col1,',','');
```

but I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'col1' in 'field list'

Comment: that is not a valid select statement.

Comment: You need a `from` clause in your `select` statement.

Comment: i did make the table mytable with col1, col2, col3

Comment: Then what is the problem - have you tried suggested statements which *include* `from` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store numbers in strings!  That is a bad representation and Oracle offers much better solutions such as nested tables or JSON.

Sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  I think the simplest method in this place is a multistep replace:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col1, ', ', '~ '), ',', ''), '~ ', ', ')
```

This assumes that `~` does not appear in the string.

Comment: Not sure why this needed a multi-step approach.  I did it with just one replace command:                                                                                   SELECT replace(INST.enterprise_name,',',' ')
from PS_INSTALLATION INST       This let me import the data without commas into Excel

Comment: @cardmagik . . . If you look carefully at the question, you'll see that not all commas are item separators, some are commas within numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Usecase : Your table have a column with varchar type, and you want to remove all the commas from the values stored in this column.

initially I wasn't sure how to apply the above mentioned solutions. This is how I achieved what I wanted.

`update book set title = replace(title,'.','') where bookid<>0`

Answer (score 0):

```
update CityNames set City = Replace(cn.City,',','') from CityNames cn
```

This worked for me, I have replaced all the commas with blankspace with this and updated the table